# Whenever I schedule my Pentaho job using the Windows Task Scheduler, a new Spoon instance is consistently opened each time the job run

Tags: pentaho-spoon

When the scheduled job is running every 2 minutes, a new Spoon instance is opened each time.

I am expecting to not open a new spoon instance evrytime i am running the job any ideas what to do in windows task scheduler.

thank you

Comment: So, the job runs successfully but a spoon instance opens, right?

Comment: Are you using kitchen.bat to run the scheduled job or using spoon.bat?

Comment: Yes it's right @Nikhil

Comment: I am using Kitchen.bat @AnaGH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start the job only once via windows task manager and have it run in the background, then in the start-step, in a job, you can schedule the job to be run every 2 min.

[image: Startoptions]

This way the job is only loaded once, and thus spoon is only started once, but the job flow-starts are repeated every 2 min